# Customize Scrolling for Onsen Page (Pull to refresh)

Tags: ios, cordova, iscroll, onsen-ui

I have a `ons-page` element that I want to customize the scrolling for. There are a few things I'd like to achieve, but mostly I want to understand what's going on.

By default, the page has `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`. This is undesirable for two reasons:

- The area "behind" the page shown during overflow is just plain white
- I have no hooks to take action on over scroll. I'd like to add pull to refresh mechanics.

I've tried working with iScroll, but the behavior I'm seeing is that if I declare my scrollable element to be inside of the page, it calculates the full element height as the visible height. If I declare my scrollable element to be the page, I can move the page around, but not the content within the page.

I'm guessing some of this is related to ["using native scrolling where it can"](https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/issues/114), but I don't really understand how that's implemented, so I'm not really sure.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`Onsen UI` doesn't support pull-to refresh as default.

How about using this library?

https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-pull-to-refresh

This is a library for `angularJS`.

## P.S

Now Onsen UI support pull-to-refresh. http://onsen.io/reference/ons-pull-hook.html

Comment: this library doesn't work neither on browser, simulator, device even it's demo